# Get PublishingPageContent rendered when using Rest Api

Tags: web-part, rest, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, publishing

I am trying to implement client-side navigation within a sharepoint site, this means, allowing the user to **navigate** thru the different **pages without reloading the browser**. I can dynamically load the **PublishingPageContent** of my Pages library items using **Ajax** and the **Rest** api, calling to something like this:

```
http://[mysite]/info/awbn/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/Items(52)?$Select=PublishingPageContent/FieldValuesAsHtml
```

However, I have a **problem**: if the **PublishingPageContent contains a webpart**, instead of getting the rendered content of it, I get something like this:

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" unselectable="on">
<div class="ms-rtestate-notify ms-rtestate-read a815f3d7-90e9-42e4-bc63-013635311f15" id="div_a815f3d7-90e9-42e4-bc63-013635311f15" unselectable="on"></div>
<div id="vid_a815f3d7-90e9-42e4-bc63-013635311f15" unselectable="on" style="display&#58;none;"></div></div>
```

This is just a simple **content Editor** webpart, displaying some text: "This is a test". How I can get a **webparts rendered version** of the publishing page content? is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance